# A class with void data member and its constructor

Tags: c++

I am trying to write C++ application which runs on Windriver linux(64bit). Here is the similar code:(Some part of my code is auto generated, I tried my best to keep it similar)

```
#include <stdio.h>

class OneClass{
     const void *data;
     public:
       OneClass(const void *inData){

          printf("In normal const %u addr: %u\n", *((unsigned int*)(inData)), inData);

          data = inData;
       }

   OneClass(){
          printf("In default const\n");
      data = NULL;
       }

   OneClass(const OneClass &in){
          printf("In copy const\n");

          data = in.data;
       }

       const void* getData(){return data;}
};

OneClass create(const unsigned &in){
     printf("In create before %u\n", in);
     return new OneClass(&in);
}

main()
{
    OneClass two = create(100);
    unsigned int *value = (unsigned int*)two.getData();
    printf("In main %u\n", *value);
}
```

And output is:

```
In create before 100
In normal const 100 addr: 4294339016
In normal const 4294339016 addr: 134520840
In main 4294339016
```

I expected two.data is 100, but it is not in real. How? I also confused how normal constructor called twice and not copy constructor?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I find it hilarious that `return new OneClass(&in);` compiles. Those addresses being the same in the output should be a hint for what's going on.

Comment: Why should the `copy constructor` be called? You are passing an `int` and not a `OneClass` object!

Comment: If you want to use `printf` to print a pointer, use the `"%p"` format, and pass a `void *` argument. Or just use `std::cout` as in a anormal C++ program, because the output operator `<<` is overloaded to handle pointers.

Comment: @chris It's because single-parameter constructors can be used implicitly by default. I don't blame the compiler for not generating a warning. A C++ compiler isn't supposed to babysit you the same way a Java compiler does. It's not going to clean up your messes for you. That's the responsibility of the coder.

Comment: @ThePcLuddite, Sure, this definitely shouldn't give a warning. The code isn't wrong, just not something that you really see that often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor `OneClass(const void*)` is being called implicitly in your `create` function. This is a feature of C++ that allows implicit object conversion.

The return type for `create` is `OneClass`. However, you return a `new OneClass(&in)`. That's a pointer to an object, not an object itself (it's type is `OneClass*`). This pointer is passed to the `OneClass(const void*)` constructor, and another `OneClass` is created with the `OneClass*` pointer. That's why your constructor is being called twice.

It's always a good idea to qualify single argument constructors with the `explicit` keyword like this:

```
explicit OneClass(const void *inData)
```

Now, this code

```
OneClass create(const unsigned &in){
     printf("In create before %u\n", in);
     return new OneClass(&in);
}
```

will cause a compiler error, and you can catch subtle errors like this.

---

This revised code works:

```
#include <cstdio> // you shouldn't include <stdio.h>, that's for C, not C++

class OneClass{
     const void *data;
     public:
       explicit OneClass(const void *inData){
          printf("In normal const %u addr: %p\n", // use the %p specifier to print pointers
                 *((unsigned int*)(inData)), inData); 
          data = inData;
       }

   OneClass(){
          printf("In default const\n");
      data = NULL;
       }

   OneClass(const OneClass &in){
          printf("In copy const\n");

          data = in.data;
       }

       const void* getData(){return data;}
};

OneClass* create(const unsigned &in){
     printf("In create before %u\n", in);
     return new OneClass(&in);
}

int main()
{
    OneClass* two = create(100);
    unsigned int *value = (unsigned int*)(*two).getData();
    printf("In main %u\n", *value);
}
```

Or to forgo dynamic memory allocation (which can get really messy, really fast) use this:

```
OneClass create(const unsigned &in){
     printf("In create before %u\n", in);
     return OneClass(&in);
}

int main()
{
    OneClass two = create(100);
    unsigned int *value = (unsigned int*)two.getData();
    printf("In main %u\n", *value);
}
```

I recommend you use the second one. Unless you have a specific need to allocate something with `new`, you shouldn't do it.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks for your answer. Could you please clarify which constructor is called to create the object two.

Comment: The `OneClass(const void *inData)` is called implicitly, because `new OneClass` returns a pointer. It matches the `const void*` parameter. That's why (unless you have a reason to do otherwise) you should use the `explicit` keyword for single argument constructors.

Comment: Yes I understood. My question(which constructor called when object two is created) is about your code, after removing new. Can you clarify now.

Comment: @Srikanth In your code (when `new` is kept), the constructor `OneClass(const void* inData)` is called __twice__. The first time it is called, it is passed `&in`. The second time it is called, it is passed `new OneClass`. However, in my second code (when `new` is removed), the constructor `OneClass(const void *inData)` is called __once__ and is passed `&in`. So, it is the same constructor in both programs, the only difference is that in your code, the first time it is used explicitly, while the second time it is used implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `create` function and that you seem to come from a Java or C# background, and bringing idioms from those languages with you to C++, idioms that don't work the same way in C++ as they do in Java or C#.

In C++ you don't need use `new` to create object instances, what `new` does is allocate memory and return a *pointer* to it. And here's the problem you're getting: The object returned from `create` is initialized with the *pointer* that you allocate by doing `new OneClass(...)`.

The simple solution is to remove that `new` operator:

```
return OneClass(...);
```